# Unable to use GNOME shell extension after installing chrome-gnome-shell

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

I followed the tutorial [here](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/) to install all the necessary packages to use gnome extensions on Firefox, Ubuntu 18.04. However, when I opened the website, it returned an error `Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector.`

I double-checked the chrome-gnome-shell, which returned `chrome-gnome-shell is already the newest version (10-1).`.

Is there any solution for this situation? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this the standard pre-installed Firefox browser?

Comment: @pomsky I think it's the standard one.

Comment: What do `apt policy firefox` and `snap list | grep -i firefox` say?